# Screen not rotating in android 8

Tags: java, android

I set the activity in AndroidManifest like below. Normally the screen should rotate if auto-rotate unlocked. But it does not rotate. When rotate the device, onConfigurationChanged method did not work. What can i do in this case?

Device: Samsung S7 Android 8

```
 <activity
        android:name=".ImageActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
        android:launchMode="singleTask"
        android:screenOrientation="fullUser"/>
```

Comment: There are multiple values you can pass to screen orientation arribute. Try with android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"

Comment: @Vijay android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" already set